# Why is setInterruptFilter not working?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to use the Android function setInterruptFilter(), but the behavior is erratic.  The following example code where I just do set/get produces strange results:

```
int filter1 = mNotificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter();

mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
int filter2 = mNotificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter();

mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
int filter3 = mNotificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter();

mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
int filter4 = mNotificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter();
```

Also note that

```
INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL = 1;
INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE = 3;
INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY = 2;
```

I am going through the [painful] permission process where every time I load my app through ADB, I manually go into settings and grant my app permission to access notifications.  I can verify this permission in code too

```
if (!mNotificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {...}
```

I only get the correct output when I begin in a state where INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL (==1).  What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of a bug in Oxygen O.S. that was resolved in version 3.2.2