# How to know whether Notifications are enabled or not for an application in android?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-settings

I've a ListView which has the list of installed applications and for each application, I need to know whether the notifications are enabled or not.
Currently I'm using below code to know if the notifications are enabled:

```
appOpsClass = Class.forName(AppOpsManager.class.getName());
Method checkOpNoThrowMethod = appOpsClass.getMethod(CHECK_OP_NO_THROW, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class);
Field opPostNotificationValue = appOpsClass.getDeclaredField(OP_POST_NOTIFICATION);
int value = (int)opPostNotificationValue.get(Integer.class);
return ((int)checkOpNoThrowMethod.invoke(mAppOps,value, appUID, appPackage) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
```

I got the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10062 does not have 
>    android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS.
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
>   W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService$Stub$Proxy.checkOperation(IAppOpsService.java:343)

I've included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS"/>
```

Still I'm getting the same error.
Using what apis can I get the value whether it is blocked or not

[image: Using what apis can I get these values?]

Comment: Which API version are you using to build the app and which android version are you testing your app on? I am asking this because for certain sensitive permissions in Android 6 and above, you need to get the permission from users on runtime. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: See if `NotificationManager.getNotificationPolicy()` does it for you. [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getNotificationPolicy())

Answer (score 9):

I am afraid this is only possible for the current application. That is why the public API of `NotificationManager` has the function `areNotificationsEnabled()` for the current package.

When looking into android source code, I found [`AppNotificationSettings`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/marshmallow-release/src/com/android/settings/notification/AppNotificationSettings.java) - application notification settings. The first switch indicates, whether notifications are blocked or not. The switch listener is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/marshmallow-release/src/com/android/settings/notification/AppNotificationSettings.java#154), which points to [`NotificationBackend`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/marshmallow-release/src/com/android/settings/notification/NotificationBackend). In this class, there is method:

[`public boolean getNotificationsBanned(String pkg, int uid)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/marshmallow-release/src/com/android/settings/notification/NotificationBackend.java#63)

which uses [`INotificationManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/INotificationManager.aidl) ( a class generated from `.aidl` file during compilation) and it's method:

[`boolean areNotificationsEnabledForPackage(String pkg, int uid);`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/INotificationManager.aidl#49)

This is Android private API, cannot be simply invoked. So I tried reflection:

```
try {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = null;
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.app.NotificationManager");
    Method method = c.getMethod("getService");
    Object obj = method.invoke(mNotificationManager);
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy");
    Method areNotificationsEnabledForPackage = clazz.getMethod("areNotificationsEnabledForPackage", String.class, int.class);
    boolean blocked = (boolean) areNotificationsEnabledForPackage.invoke(obj, getPackageName(), android.os.Process.myUid());
    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), String.valueOf(blocked));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, as you can see, you must first create `NotificationManager`. Sadly, this class is created for package. So the code above will for only for :

```
boolean blocked = (boolean) areNotificationsEnabledForPackage.invoke(obj, getPackageName(), android.os.Process.myUid());
```

however this will not work :

```
//InvocationTargetException will be thrown.
boolean blocked = (boolean) areNotificationsEnabledForPackage.invoke(obj, "com.android.camera", 10040);
```

**Conclusion:**

Cannot be done.

Comment: I know this is very old, but you can do `final INotificationManager iNotificationManager = INotificationManager.Stub.asInterface(
                 ServiceManager.getService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));` and get the actual running service instance and not a re-created per-package one. Will this allow you to check for other packages without ITE?

Answer (score 2):

See if you can use NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat.html#areNotificationsEnabled()

[Android 4.1: How to check notifications are disabled for the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application)

Comment: NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled() gives whether notifications are enabled for the running application. What is needed is to check if a given application (with UID and package name) has notifications turned off (block all) or not