# get info from notificationcompact from package installed

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications, android-context

I need to know when a package installed on the cell phone can send notifications here is the code where the applications that are on the cell phone are read and I need to know if it has notifications enabled through NotificationManagerCompat (areNotificationsEnabled ())

```
 List<String> paquetenombre = new ArrayList<>();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED );
     List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context1.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
```

, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. An application can only use  `NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()` to determine if its own notifications are blocked or not. There is no way to determine if notifications for another application are blocked.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39976045/769265

Comment: tks... another way to do this ?, I rephrase the question, how to know if installed apps have permission to notify

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to determine this. Sorry.