# Is there a way to hide or disable Heads-Up Notifications temporarily?

Tags: java, android, screen-recording, heads-up-notifications

I am searching everywhere for this and the closest thing to an answer i got was [this](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example) which could not block the heads-up notifications.

I am creating a custom screen record app and it annoyies me when heads up notifications show up in my app while recording.

Is there any way i can hide or disable every incoming notification while the screen is recording ?!

I would appreciate if you can give me an example that works on a non rooted device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you can clear notifications through the NotificationManager as they come.

> In API 23+ you can use both
>   NotificationManager#setNotificationPolicy() and
>   NotificationManager#setInterruptionFilter() (in that specific order)
>   to control which notifications are shown to the user. Permissions are
>   required for those APIs. Notice that this methods seem to be a
>   convenience to be able to access the functionality, but skip
>   implementing a complete NotificationListenerService. That's the only
>   option that can work in a satisfying way

Details: [How do some apps block/replace heads-up notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685835/how-do-some-apps-block-replace-heads-up-notifications/39985892)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been trying all the given solutions but the heads-up notifications are not blocked or hidden, just the notifications are deleted which is not much of a help for me.

Comment: A little more detail, not sure if it helps. Other than this, the general answer seems to be no--there do seem to be some work-around methods with inconsistent results though.

Comment: There are some apps like HeadsOff (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.noheadsup&hl=de) but according to the reviews it is not consistent throughout devices. Anyways, thank you for your help, i appreciate it.

Comment: The last option (quoted) still seems promising though, maybe worth a try